# why the hindi text is changing in symbol in android development

Tags: java, android, multipart, json, android-ion

I am trying to fetch the value same as client paste in editView.
Before the below code I print **story** and get the text in hindi same as client paste.

**Android code**

```
 Ion.with(Createfunction.this)
                .load(url)
                .setTimeout(60 * 1000)
                /*added by sash 16.4.2016*/                   
                .setMultipartParameter("story", story)                   
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject jsonObject) {
                        commonMethods.dismissWithCheck(materialDialog);
                        if (e == null) {
                          Log.d("oncomplete...", e + "it is null");
                            Boolean success = jsonObject.get("success").getAsBoolean();
                            if (success) {
                            //successfully done
                            }
                        }
                });
```

with the help of this code I am sending story to server and print there but this time I am getting hindi text like ................

à¤?à¤¯ à¤¨à¥? à¤?à¤? à¤¬à¤¯à¤¾à¤¨ à¤®à¥?à¤? à¤?à¤¹à¤¾Â , 'à¤®à¥?à¤?à¤¨à¥? 'à¤µà¥?à¤?à¤¸ à¤?à¤« à¤?à¤?à¤¡à¤¿à¤¯à¤¾' à¤?à¤¾ à¤ªà¤¹à¤²à¤¾ à¤¸à¥?à¤?à¤¨ 
à¤¦à¥?à¤?à¤¾ à¤¹à¥?,

I don't have much idea about android where the text format is going to change. how I can resolve it. Please help to find the solution.